# Visual Basic random number with seed but in reverse

Tags: vb.net, random, random-seed

I wish to generate a random number between 1 and 26 with a seed but then wish to get the same numbers back when I provide the function with the same seed.

The `Rnd` and `Randomize` functions aren't suitable for this as they always return a completely random number, regardless of the seed.

Comment: "The Rnd and Randomize functions aren't suitable for this as they always return a completely random number, regardless of the seed."  I'd have to disagree with you on that.  Show us your code...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I have already completed what I wanted with the answer from Bathsheba, but thank you for your concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bizarrely, you need to call Rnd(-1) first, then Randomize(n) with n the seed.

Subsequent calls to Rnd() will always give you the same sequence

e.g.

```
Sub test()

    Call Rnd(-1)
    Call Randomize(0)
    For n = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print Rnd
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: It's worth noting that these functions are old VB6 functions which are still supported primarily for backwards compatibility.  New .NET code should, instead, use the `Random` class.  +1, however, for providing an answer using the old functions as requested :)

Answer (score 1):

Use new instances of [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class is one possible solution, and initialize each instance with the same seed.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim yourSeed = 40 'Or whatever your seed it
    Dim random1 As New System.Random(yourSeed)
    Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 16
    Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 14
    Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 19

    Dim random2 As New System.Random(yourSeed)
    Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 16
    Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 14
    Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 26)) 'Prints 19
End Sub
```